# Windows 10: use 3 jacks for speakers and headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio

So, I've integrated sound card on my motherboard, and it has 3 aux sockets( not sure terminology is on the spot here. I have 3 female jacks ). Now, I have headphones with integrated mic that only has one jack. I've bought the aux splitter for my headphones, and now I've headphones with two jacks, that go into green( out ) and red( in ) aux sockets.

What I'm left with is the blue aux socket, which I'd like to use as aux out for my speakers. Is that by any chance possible on Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this simple explanatory image on [Tom's Hardware](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/what-audio-jacks-are-which.3098416/)
[image]

This explains the variants & socket colours from 2-channel up to 8- channel audio.
You have 2-channel, so you will have just the top three sockets - blue, green & *pink* [not red].
You can see from the chart below that Pink is mic in, green is stereo out - this is how you mapped your headset using the splitter cable. [Laptops these days tend to have a single headset socket which isn't included in the above colour coding.]

Your problem is that the blue socket is a **line in**. This is usually fixed in hardware, there is no software control to change its function.

Your alternatives are -
Swap plugs when you need to change devices.
Check there's no supplementary sockets on the front of the computer; sometimes there's a headset socket.
Buy a separate USB sound card. Depending on type, this would either enable both outputs at once, or some kind of software switching.

Comment: Thanks. Primary question simplified would be whether I can control blue socket with software to decide whether it's in or out, but apparently not.